# How to print only selections made in multi-selection box

Tags: javascript, html, multibox

I'm working on my 1st personal project. I have a multi-selection box in a form page and I am trying to figure out the best way to show the selections made in the multi selection box right underneath the box in a list. Thanks in advance!

```
<select
  id="selectcrim"
  multiple="multiple"
  onchange="showResults(this, event)"
  size="10"
>
  <option selected>None</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<ul id="selectedresults"></ul>
```

```js
function results(element, event) {
  let result = document.getElementById("selectedresults");
  while (result.firstChild) result.removeChild(result.firstChild);
  let values = [];
  for (const i = 0; i < element.options.length; i++) {
    if (element.options[i].selected) {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(element.options[i].value));
      result.appendChild(li);
    }
  }
}
```

I expected the selected results to appear in list form underneath the multi-box however nothing seems to happen.

Comment: For begin with, the `<option>`s should go inside the `<select>`

Comment: Thanks very much. I actually I had them in the <select> so I will change that in my sample code.

Comment: You have trivial errors: `result` is not `showResults` and `i++` is  not going to work when you have `const i`. Such problems are easy to find, since the error messages in the console give enough clues.